# Как рассчитать рикошет?

Tags: javascript, typescript, математика

У меня есть два тела круглой формы, они движутся на встречу друг к другу и сталкиваются. При столкновении вектора их направления движения должны измениться. Как их рассчитать? (массы одинаковые, трения нет, размер не важен)
V1={x1,y1} V2={x2,y2} N={x3,y3}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мое предположение что так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(x1*x3+y1*y3) / sqrt(x1^2 + x3^2) * sqrt(y1^2+y3^2) = получим число F и умножим так вектор V1 - (x1*F, y1*F)

Попробовал просто сложить вектора N+V1 вроде похоже получилось

Comment: массы одинаковые? Удары упругие? Трения нет? Вращение есть? Размером можно пренебречь?

Comment: @pavel да массы одинаковые трения нет, да размер не важен. Но вообще чем точнее и полнее будет ответ тем лучше, особенно тем кто будет заходить и читать, может им остальные параметры тоже пригодятся. Для меня важно приблизительно куда направить объект после столкновения

Comment: Для начала надо высчитать точные координаты коллизии. Со сферами/кругами - это делается очень просто. А дальше, вот развёрнутый ответ https://toster.ru/q/31059

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich добавляйте уточнения в тело вопроса, чтобы тот, кто читает вопрос, сразу их видел

Comment: С трением и вращением поинтереснее, если вдруг надо - рабочую ф-ю можно найти в любом OpenSource биллиарде)

Comment: не ясно вобще зачем вот это `N + V1` - зачем вы прибавляете к вектору скорости вектор, длина которого есть расстояние между центрами кругов ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вобщем, сперва как уже сказали в комментариях, нужно определить пересекаются ли круги - для этого нужно добавить условие

`if (distBetweebCirles <= circle1.radius + circle2.radius) {
  //  collision happened
  //  resolve it
}`

в вашем случае `distBetweenCirles` это длина вектора `N`(пожалуйста, обозначьте его как то подругому, например `distanceVector`), а радиус можно считать эквивалентным массе при симуляции.

Далее, допустим круги сталкиваются, так как массы одинаковые, то векторы скоростей просто обменяются друг с другом. Это следует из следующей формулы (которая также применима и для случая с разнымы массами)

`1)`

`v1 = (u1 * (m1 - m2) + 2 * m2 * u2) / (m1 + m2)`

`v2 = (u2 * (m1 - m2) + 2 * m1 * u1) / (m1 + m2)`

где `u1, u2` векторы скоростей до столкновения, а `v1, v2` после.
И если `m1 == m2` то получаем

`2)`

`v1 = u2`

и соотвественно

`v2 = u1`
(как это вышло выведите сами из формулы `1)`)

*Откуда взялась первая формула ?* - при таком упругом столкновении действуют [закон сохранения импульса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%B0) и [закон сохранения энергии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8)

следовательно, необходимо решить систему уравнений относительно `v1` и `v2`:

`m1 * u1 + m2 * u2 = m1 * v1 + m2 * v2`

`(m1 * u1^2) / 2 + (m2 * u2^2) / 2 = (m1 * v1^2) / 2 + (m2 * v2^2) / 2`

решение которого есть формула `1)`

читать подробнее про мат часть [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80#.D0.90.D0.B1.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.82.D0.BD.D0.BE_.D1.83.D0.BF.D1.80.D1.83.D0.B3.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D1.83.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.80)